# c# NLog custom delimiter in programmatic configuration

Tags: c#, customization, nlog

I'm using NLog in VS2019 and when setting up the logger programmatic (no external nlog configuration file) before first use, I define the loggers there like

```
var logConsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget()
{
    Name = "logconsole",
    Layout = "${longdate}|${level:upperCase=true}|${message}"
};
config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logConsole));
```

Currently I have the delimiter `|` hardcoded there.

How can I make the delimiter variable? Defining a `string delim = "|"` and then setting Layout to `Layout = "${longdate}${delim}${level:upperCase=true}${delim}${message}"` does not work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a context construction for that in NLog, e.g. the `GlobalDiagnosticsContext`.

Example:

```
var logConsole = new NLog.Targets.ColoredConsoleTarget()
{
    Name = "logconsole",
    Layout = "${longdate}${gdc:item=delimiter}${level:upperCase=true}${gdc:item=delimiter}${message}"
};
config.LoggingRules.Add(new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logConsole));
```

And set in your code:

```cs
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("delimiter", "|");
```

You could change the delimiter then in code in other places.

The `GlobalDiagnosticsContext` is global for the whole application. If you need a more limited scope, that's also possible! See [NLog - Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
string delim = "|";
Layout = "${longdate}" +delim+"${level:upperCase=true}"+delim+"${message}";
```

The `${}` syntax, denotes what will be replaced. So to concatenate with a string variable, you need to add the characters with string concatenation.

Comment: I wanted to prevent string concatination in connection with nlog as much as possible.